# JavaScript webdriver-selenium `mouseMove` inaccurate on Chromium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium-embedded

Running Chromedriver through NodeJs - `protractor` and `selenium-webdriver` - against an embedded Chromium on Windows 10.

It seems that using `getLocation` returns accurate positions, but when I try to have WebDriver move the mouse to those positions, the mouse doesn't get there -- unless I multiply the positions by about 1.45.

Surely that can't be right?

This is the first time I've used Selenium in years, but I'm sure I haven't had to do this before.

Below is an abbreviation of the code, with some of the webdriver log: 
 1. move the mouse to an element, 
 1. depress the mouse button,
 1. wait a little for the system under to test to react, 
 1. move the mouse a little for the system under test, 
 1. wait a little, 
 1. move to a target element 
 1. release the mouse button.

The code works, provided I change nothing, and only move vertically.

If I move vertically, I see no effect.

If I run code twice in one Chromium window, loading the test document at the start of each run, the second run hangs around document loading.

```
var destLocation,
    fromEl = $('elementA'),
    destEl = $('elementB');

destEl.getLocation()
    .then(() => {
      browser.driver.actions()
        .mouseMove( fromEl, {x: 10, y: 10} )
        // 09:56:37.222 INFO - Done: [mousemove: 5 true]
        .mouseDown( fromEl, {x: 10, y: 10} )
        // 09:56:37.230 INFO - Done: [mousedown: no args]
        .perform();
    })
    .then(() => {
      browser.sleep(400);
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Business logic requires this
      browser.driver.actions().mouseMove( fromEl, {x:15, y:15} )
        // 09:56:37.719 INFO - Done: [mousemove: 5 true]
        .mouseDown()
        // 09:56:37.726 INFO - Done: [mousedown: no args]
        .perform();
    })
    .then(() => {
      browser.sleep(400);
    })
    .then(() => {
      browser.driver.actions().mouseMove( $('body'), destLocation ).perform();
      // 09:56:38.209 INFO - Done: [mousemove: 9 true]
    })
    .then(() => {
      browser.sleep(200);
    })
    .then(() => {
      browser.driver.actions().mouseUp().perform();
      // 09:56:38.425 INFO - Done: [mouseup: nothing]
    });
```

- Selenium v2.52.0, with Core v2.52.0. Built from revision 4c2593c
- Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
- OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
- Java: Oracle Corporation 25.91-b14
- chromedriver_2.21 and chromedriver_2.15.322448 seem to act the same way
- CEF 3.2454.1344.g2782fb8
- Chromium  45.0.2454.101
- WebKit  537.36
- JavaScript  4.5.103.35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported to the Chromium team as a bug, who could not reproduce the issue with the latest versions of all libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for mouse hover in selenium javascript:-

```
const actions = driver.actions({bridge: true});
var elem=await driver.findElement(By.id("myId"));
await actions.move({duration:5000,origin:elem,x:0,y:0}).perform();
```

This code has to be inside an async function as await is used, or else to use with promise, this code might help:-

```
const actions = driver.actions({bridge: true});
driver.findElement(By.id("myId")).then((elem)=>{
  actions.move({duration:5000,origin:elem,x:0,y:0}).perform();
});
```

hope it helps....

Comment: I must have missed duration being the key to triggering mouseup events in the docs. This was a life saver.