# Selenium WebDriver simulate mousemove event with movementX and movementY other than zero

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, capybara, mouseevent, selenium-chromedriver

I want to test my web application using selenium webdriver and I can't get `mousemove` event invoked with `movementX` or `movementY` other than `0`.

I've tried using `Class: Selenium::WebDriver::ActionBuilder`:

```
driver.action.move_to(element).move_by(1,1).perform()
```

And javascript hacks like [this](http://marcgrabanski.com/simulating-mouse-click-events-in-javascript/).

Is there any other way to invoke/induce `MouseEvent` of type `mousemove` taking into account that `movementX` and `movementY` is important?

Comment: This question has been answered in this link:-
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295866/9682597)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium-webdrivers `#move_to` accepts right  and down offsets for the element you're moving to.  When using capybara with selenium-webdriver, assuming you have found the element you want to move the mouse to, you should be able to do

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(element.native, 1, 1).perform
```

Note: this will only work with the selenium driver, not with Poltergeist, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I looked up the description of it and it says:  
_Moves the mouse to the middle of the given element. The element is scrolled into view and its location is calculated using getBoundingClientRect. Then the mouse is moved to optional offset coordinates from the element._  
Theoretically it should work, but apparently the logic behind is the same in all cases, it just warps virtual mouse in the right position.

Comment: @Zaimatsu  Ah - yes it does just warp there -- there are no move events created along the way.  The w3c webdriver spec for pointer actions is currently being finalized - https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#pointer-actions - and drivers are beginning to implement the spec so this should change over time, but as of now you won't get those events with any driver.